# How to write a better zend model class and avoid writing again and again adapters in each method

Tags: model, zend-db-table

Here is the basic code that I use for my zend framework models.

```
class Model_FormMapper extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{ 
    protected $_name    = 'tblMapper'; 
    protected $_primary     = 'mapId';

    public function insertColumns($arrData){

  $db               = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();        
      $sql              = $this->insert($arrData);
      $lastId       = $this->_db->lastInsertId();
      return $lastId;
   }
}
```

One thing that I don't like in my models is initialisation of 
adpter in each method.
$db     = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();

Can any one tell me a better solution for writing zend models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer I can set a database connection variable in registry and can use any where eg: `$this->_db`.

```
class Model_FormMapper extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{ 
   protected $_name    = 'tblMapper'; 
   protected $_primary     = 'mapId';


  public function insertColumns($arrData){

     $sql              = $this->insert($arrData);
     $lastId           = $this->_db->lastInsertId();
     return $lastId;
  }
}
```